# Consultar com Sequelize em duas tabelas

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

Tenho 2 tabelas

```
const Fornecedor = database.define('fornecedor', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    nome: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
})

module.exports = Fornecedor;
```

```
const Item = database.define('item', {
   id: {
       type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
       autoIncrement: true,
       allowNull: false,
       primaryKey: true
   },
   nome: {
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
       allowNull: false
   },
   localizacao: {
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
       allowNull: false,
       unique: true
   }
})

Item.belongsTo(Fornecedor, { foreignKey: "fornecedorId", targetKey: "id" });
module.exports = Item;
```

Preciso retornar da seguinte forma:
[{Fornecedor1, {itensdoFornecedor1}}, {Fornecedor2, {itensdoFornecedor2}}]

Isso para usar em uma mat table que expande o Fornecedor e mostra os itens dele.

```
const Itens = require("../models/Itens");
const Fornecedores = require("../models/Fornecedores");

module.exports = class LocalizacoesController {
  static listLocalizacoes(req, res) {    
    try {
      const fornecedoresItens = [];

      const f = Fornecedores.findAll({raw: true})
      .then(fornecedores => {
        fornecedores.forEach(
          (fornecedor) => {
            const i = Itens.findAll({where: {fornecedorId: fornecedor.id}, raw: true})
            .then(itens => {
              let fornecedorItens = [fornecedor, itens];
              fornecedoresItens.push(fornecedorItens);
              console.log(fornecedorItens);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message));

      Promise.all([f, i])
      .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({ result });
      })
      .catch (err => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }

  }
};
```

Mas o código não retorna o 200 e assim o Array necessário, só fica girando e girando.
Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Olá, pelo que vi em seu código há um erro na declaração de variaveis.

Você declara  `const i = ...` dentro do bloco `then` (na linha 13) da busca de fornecedores, porém tenta usar ele fora desse bloco de código (na linha 25)

```
 Promise.all([f, i])
      .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({ result });
      })
```